# How do I make a media player control notification in Gtk?

Tags: python, controls, gtk, media-player

In Rhythmbox (GNOME's music player), when it's playing music, you can open the notifications panel and control the music playback from there. Here's a screenshot. The playback controls are bordered in orange; they have a little music note icon:

[image]

This is what I want to make; the media playback controls. Note that, while it *is* in the notifications panel, it's not technically a notification, because it never pops up on the screen, and you can't make it go away. In the screenshot, you can see the actual notification, which I don't want to make, *below* the controls.

I know that there's a `Gio.Notification`, but it's not quite what I need (unless I'm very much mistaken). I searched in `Gio`, `Gdk`, and `Gtk`, but I didn't find anything. I also searched, among other things, `[gtk] media control` and `[gtk] media notification` on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find anything there either.

Thanks to the help of [BobMorane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6575139/bobmorane), I've now figured out that Rhythmbox uses `libnotify` for its player controls. I know how to create actions using `Notify.Notification`, and I can make them have images, etc., but what I still haven't figured out is how to:

1. Make the notification so that it can't be closed;
2. Make it so that the action buttons are *next* to the icon and text, not under;
3. Keep the notification on top of all the others in the notifications panel.

Using Python's `help()` function to look at `gi.repository.Notify.Notification`, the only methods I see that seem to have potential are `add_action()` (particularly its `user_data` parameter) and `set_hint()` (and its variants). Could these be used to achieve my goal?

How do I make a media-control "notification" in Gtk with Python, as explained above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the technology used by Rhytmbox to acheive this is [MPRIS](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mpris-spec/) (**M**edia **P**layer **R**emote **I**nterfacing **S**pecification). As they say on their we page:

> The Media Player Remote Interfacing Specification (MPRIS) is a
> standard D-Bus interface which aims to provide a common programmatic
> API for controlling media players.
>
> It provides a mechanism for discovery, querying and basic playback
> control of compliant media players, as well as a tracklist interface
> which is used to add context to the active media item.

In Rhythmbox, this is implemented as a core [plug-in](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/tree/master/plugins/mpris). The code is pretty complicated, but basically implements the [MPRIS specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/fullindex.html). This implementation then exposes some information and controls out to other applications which want to control the Rhythmbox, like the [Gnome Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) in your case. If you deactivate the MPRIS plug-in, the "notification player" will no longer work.

In GNOME Shell, you can see they have their own MPRIS module as well (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/mpris.js), which is used to:

1. Respond to player notifications and display information (album art, title, buttons, etc).
2. Send notifications to the player (ex.: pause the song).

In this module, the formatting of the buttons and all that stuff comes into life as well. This means that on your part (the player's designer), you should have no UI formatting to do (you don't have control over this, GNOME Shell has). What you need to do is expose what is needed by the GNOME Shell by implementing the MPRIS interfaces.

(As a side note: the `calendar.js` file is the one implementing the notification list, and you can see it uses MPRIS "notifications", which it puts on top of standard notifications.)

There exist Python libraries to do so, such as Mopidy-MPRIS, bit their support for the GNOME Shell seems [not to be working at the moment](https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy-mpris#gnome-shell-builtin). You may have to look for D-Bus related libraries on FreeDesktop.org. There exists many [bindings](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/), with some in Python.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Your answers have been quite helpful in figuring out the solution. I've updated my question based on my updated knowledge; basically, all I need to know now his how to set certain properties of the notification (it seems that `plugin` in the Rhythmbox source code is important to this). You can continue looking into the problem, but you're also free to move on if you wish; it's up to you. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Sure! I'll do that as soon as I get the time. It's been a bit of a busy day for me, so I may not get around to it until tomorrow.

Comment: This will be my last contribution on this topic, I really hope it helps you!

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you so much for all your work and research on this topic. Knowing what it's called and how it works is extremely valuable. I'll accept this answer, but you _also_ deserve a bounty! (I'll award it tomorrow, when the 23 hour restriction is over). +75 rep is enough for you to earn a new [moderation privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions); enjoy :-)!

Comment: Many thanks, it was my pleasure (I learned lots of things along the way!)